# want to send hexadecimal string data in java

Tags: java, javascript, android

I have Integer data in char[] array. example: 12, 03, 10.
I want to sent the data as hexadecimal format in string.

example : 0C030A

But after converting into hexadecimal, I am getting C3A.
kindly suggest me to get the right data as 0C030A.

I am using the following code

```
String messageBody = "A3";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM:dd:yy:HH:mm:ss");
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date(mLocation.getTime()));
char[] temp;
temp = currentDateandTime.split(delimiter);
for( int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++ )
{
    messageBody += Integer.toHexString (Integer.parseInt( temp[i]));
}
```

Comment: dear Nambari, Thanks for your quick response. I tried with radix as you suggested. But still I am getting C3A and not 0C030A.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) with `"%02x"` for that. `02` means pad with zeros until length of 2. `x` means hex.

```
messageBody += String.format("%02x", Integer.parseInt(temp[i]));
```

Comment: Please select his post as the answer

Answer (score 0):

`String.format()` can be fairly heavyweight where performance is a concern (lots of orphan objects created and immediately thrown away).

If you want something a little tighter you can do something like this:

```
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("0x00000000");
String fmt(int item) {

    int tmp;
    char c;

    for (int i = 9; i >= 2; i--) {

        tmp = (item & 0xF); item >>= 4;
        c = (char) (tmp < 10 ? '0' + tmp : 'A' + tmp - 10);
        sb.setCharAt(i, c);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

you could optimise this even further (ie use less variables and perform less iterations), but I think this is exhaustive enough for now :) not Thread-safe etc.